# The difference between action and behavior

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I don't seem to find any difference between action as a noun and behavior. What's the difference between these two words?

Once I used the word ‘action’ to describe what a character of a movie did for example

> Her action in the movie symbolizes blah blah ...

That was not something she did in her daily life, but a simple decision she'd made and followed through. In that case, would action be the right one to be used or behavior be the right one?

Comment: An action means a single action. A prolonged or repeated action can be called an activity. Behaviour means either a repeated action or a certain pattern of how someone behaves.

Answer (score 3):

**Action** is the *act* of doing something.

**Behaviour** is more about the *way* in which you act.

For example, when two chemicals are mixed, an action occurs (a *re*action, in fact). The *way* in which those two chemicals (or the compound they create) act may be described as a "behaviour".

In *human behaviour*, a collection of different actions, possibly recurring actions, may collectively be called a behaviour. A child described as "behaving badly" at school may have a history of kicking, punching, screaming etc - all individual actions that make up a behaviour or behavioural pattern.

The fact they are not always interchangeable is evidence of them having separate meanings. For example:

> To end poverty would require *action*.

You couldn't directly substitute this with "*behaviour*", although you might say...

> To end poverty would require changes in behaviour.

...which might imply a series of new actions, collectively described as a behaviour.